# StackEdit: cannot start server.js

Tags: stackedit

After installing StackEdit:

```
git clone https://github.com/benweet/stackedit
cd stackedit
npm install
bower install
(export PORT=5000 && node server.js)
```

It reports the errors:

[image]

I googled without finding any solutions. Could any one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the difference. This time I just download and unzip the zip file from Github. And follow the official instruction:

```
npm install
bower install
(export PORT=80 && node server.js)
```

It works.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error when I was trying to set the port to 80, but was fine with 5000. So you may try to change the port to others to see if it works. For example:

```
(export PORT=3000 && node server.js)
```